# Why does this object get destroyed twice?

Tags: c++, std, destructor

I have this C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Obj {
public:
  Obj() {
    std::cout << "build" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Obj() {
    std::cout << "destroy" << std::endl;
  }
};

static std::vector<Obj> s = { Obj() };

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```bash
build
destroy
destroy
```

So why does the object get destroyed twice? Shouldn't it only get destroyed once?

Comment: Add the address of `this` to the `cout` call in the destructor...

Comment: There's probably a copy construction occuring somewhere?

Comment: You may want to read about implicit contractors.

Comment: You may also want to try `static std::vector<Obj> s(1);` instead.

Comment: Here's a demo that should clarify what's happening: https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/Ydcbfbcfr. You can try changing the code and see what happens as a result.

Comment: You didn't exhaust all the ways an `Obj` can be creatged. (Hint: there is an implicit `Obj(Obj const&)` that you didn't implement but it exists anyhow).

Comment: If you are going to add prints to the constructor and destructor make sure you print in all the constructors. Remember there are several constructors that the compiler will generate automatically for you (so you should override those and add print). See Rule of 3/5